Combining configurations into next.config.js
I have 2 next.config.js files.  I do not understand how to combine them or extend one of them.
This one has interesting logic.
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants');

module.exports = (phase) => {
  console.log(PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);
  if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) {
    return {
      env: {
        mongodb_username: 'maxxxxxan',
        mongodb_password: '2YkxxxxPk0vqp',
        mongodb_clustername: 'cluster0',
        mongodb_database: 'my-site-dev',
      },

    };
  }

  return {
    env: {
      mongodb_username: 'maxxxxxlian',
      mongodb_password: '2Ykcxxxxx0vqp',
      mongodb_clustername: 'cluster0',
      mongodb_database: 'my-site',
    },
  };
};

This one has the logic I need for using sqlite3 on the dev server.
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig

